# Getting VBox IIS to use shared volume for website physcial path

Tags: iis, directory, virtual-machine, virtualbox, shared

Im trying to use a VM as the webserver to test code and design changes made to content on development systems.  The following what I am doing.

Create Windows 7 Enterprise VM on  Virtual Box
On Virtual Box share the Web development folder on Host system
in IIS on VBox I select the share  \Vboxsvr\WebDev\Site1  as the physical path for the website.  IIS doesn't complain it can't see this volume when I do this.

when I try to preview the site on the Vbox Guest  I get a 500.19 error , it appears that it can't read the files.    I am suspecting permissions issues,  any idea how to resolve this?

(By the way I have tried this With VMware as well but iis won't even recognize shared folders.)

Comment: Exact same issue... I'll post an answer if I happen to figure it out.